# How to construct a character based seq2seq model in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

What changes are required to the existing seq2seq model in tensorflow so that I can use character units rather then the existing word units for the seq2seq task? And will this be a good configuration for a predictive ext application?

The following function signatures may need modification for this task:

```
def embedding_rnn_seq2seq(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, cell,
                          num_encoder_symbols, num_decoder_symbols,
                          output_projection=None, feed_previous=False,
                          dtype=dtypes.float32, scope=None):
```

Apart from reduced input output vocabulary what other parameter changes would be be required to implement such a character level seq2seq model ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the existing seq2seq model in tensorflow without any code changes for character-based units if you prepare your input data files by whitespace separating your training examples like this:

```
The quick brown fox.
```

Becomes:

```
T h e _SPACE_ q u i c k _SPACE_ b r o w n _SPACE_ f o x .
```

Then your vocabulary naturally becomes characters not words.

You can experiment vocab sizes, with embedding size, eliminate embedding layer, etc. to see what works best for your data.